# If $(X,\leq)$ is a set with a total order, how can I show that there is $Y\supset X$ s.t. $Y$ has the supremum property?

Tags: order-theory

In my course, they defined $\mathbb R$ as the smallest set that contain $\mathbb Q$ and that has the supremum property, i.e. that all upper-bounded set has a supremum.

1) My problem, it's that I don't know how I can be sure that such a set indeed exist. I'm not so sure how to construct it.

2) Also, if I can build such a set, how can I define $x\leq y$ if $x,y\notin \mathbb Q$.

---

I know that this question is not as general than my title. But at the end, I wonder how to do in the very general case.

Comment: This is called the *Dedekind completion* of a linear order. Essentially, you look at bounded sets without a supremum, and you artificially add that supremum if it does not exist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks a lot. And does this completion will automatically gives comparable numbers ? if $A$ and $B$ are bounded without supremum, what would assure that $\sup(A)$ and $\sup(B)$ are comparable ?

Comment: Well, if some elements of $B$ are larger than *all* elements of $A$, then they are at least as big as $\sup A$ and at least as small as $\sup B$. Or vice versa. Or, the two sets are "intertwined" and therefore would have the same new supremum.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you. Very last question, after reading dedekind completion on wikipedia, I have the impression that at the end, there is only one set $E\supset \mathbb Q$ s.t. $E$ has the supremum property. Whereas my lecture said that $\mathbb R$ is defined to be the smallest one. So, I was wondering, are they sets $E$ with the supremum property such that $\mathbb R\subsetneq E$ ?

Comment: There is only one such linearly ordered set in which $\Bbb Q$ *is dense*. That is to say, if you have two Dedekind-complete partial orders, and each of them has a copy of $\Bbb Q$ which is dense (that is, every point is the supremum of a set of rational numbers (from the relevant copy)), then the two linear orders are isomorphic. Of course we can have *larger* linear orders, they will simply have points which are not supremum of any set of rationals, though.

Comment: If we avoid $\mathbb Q$, but consider $(X,\leq )$ a set with a total order without the property of supremum. Is there only one $Y$ s.t. $Y\supset X$ with the supremum property, or we can have several ? Like $Z$ with supremum property s.t. $X\subset Y\subsetneq Z$.

Comment: The argument is the same, the idea is the same. The fact I mentioned the rationals is irrelevant. This is why we call it *the* Dedekind-completion.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, one has to construct this set. Call a pair $(L, R)$ of proper subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ a **Dedekind cut** if :

1. $L \cup R = \mathbb{Q}$
2. $\forall x \in L, \ \forall y \in R, \ x < y$

One can then define $\mathbb{R}$ as the union of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the set $D$ of all Dedekind cuts. One can then define the order $<'$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows :

- for $q, l \in \mathbb{Q}$, $q <' l :\Longleftrightarrow q < l$
- for $c = (L, R) \in D$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$,
  $c <' q :\Longleftrightarrow \forall x \in L, \ x < q$ and
  $q <' c :\Longleftrightarrow \forall x \in R, \ q < x$
- for $c = (L,R) \in D$ and $d = (L', R') \in D$,
  $c < d :\Longleftrightarrow \exists x \in L', \ \forall y \in L, \ y < x$